# Hiding substituted value in HTML email template with CSS

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

My ITSM application can send HTML emails using templates but it uses simple substitution of keywords like [keyword1] which presence of (not null) I want to abuse to dynamically show or hide some data.

For example the template might be:

```
<body>
  <span>some label: [keyword1]</span>
</body>
```

Since most email clients won't run any client side scripts and the substitution engine on my ITSM is very limited I though I could use css with selectors to hide span if it has some (any) class and the class would be set to actual replaced value.

I came up with css:

```
span {visibility: visible; display: block; }
span[class|=''] {visibility: hidden; display: none; }
```

then in html template body:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
  <tr>
    <td width="200" valign="top"><span class="[something]">[something]</span></td>
    <td width="200" valign="top"><span class="">empty class value</span></td>
    <td width="200" valign="top"><span>span without class</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So the idea is that if replacement token value exists it will be assigned as class of the span hence remain visible but if it does not the class name will be empty hence hide span. The span without any class would also be visible.
This works fine in Chrome when testing the concept and is hiding "empty class value" span only but does not work in actual email client Outlook 2010.

Besides the fact that this approach is cumbersome while creating correct template since any span with any class will be hidden can anyone suggest how this can be achieved otherwise?

EDIT: I have changed subject to better reflect the question

Comment: Unfortunately you have to inline all your styles - and that's if Outlook supports the CSS rules you are using. This is because since 2007, Outlook uses Word as it's rendering engine, instead of IE like it did before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the solution could be trivial. Since substituted value can be empty all that needs to be done is to use selector for empty class i.e.:

```
span[class=""] {visibility: hidden; display: none; }
```

Any other value will be shown as per default span style including ones without class.

However, Outlook does not support that [selector](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

So the only way I can think of to achieve this is to prepend something to the replacement token. If value of replacement is empty then only what prepended will be left in the class name.

Final solution therefore is:

```
// in CSS
span.hide {visibility: hidden; display: none; }
// then in HTML template body
<span class="hide[somekey1]">Label: [somekey1]</span>
```

Which I tested with positive effect.

Answer (score 0):

You're using CSS3, which is too advanced for Outlook.

I'm not even sure what your `[class|='']` selector does; [`[foo|='bar']`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors) says that attribute `foo` must have a hyphen-separated list of values and `bar` must be the first, so either `[class|='']` will match `<span class="-thing">` or it will match any `span` with a `class` attribute regardless of its content.

I think you want the latter, so you might as well do it the CSS2 way:

```
span {visibility: visible; display: block; }
span[class] {visibility: hidden; display: none; }
```

Also note that `visibility: hidden` removes the element but keeps its place while `display: none` remove the element entirely, without keeping its spacing.  You can probably remove both `visibility`  declarations.

I don't have Outlook to confirm this on, but you should have more luck with this code than the CSS3 code you were using before.

Comment: Thanks Adam, that seems reasonable. I will test and update tomorrow.